# Upload image or file with jquery function just with it no php no more codes needed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have search the whole google and find nothing now i need serious help by you the great coders and i know you can solve my issue.

Suppose that i need to upload a file or images through just with jquery function or just with javascript code how would it be.

Here I need function to work like this.

```
<script>
    function jsFunction(){
            alert('Hello World!');
        };
</script>
<form action="#" onSubmit="jsFunction()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" value="file">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In this code I have describe that when file would be selected function jsFunction would be call and what should be the next step how to upload the file with simple code in jquery javascript without any code of php or any else. Please help me to solve this issue!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: sorry but to upload WHERE???

Comment: Files and images would need to upload at my own project server. Please help me there would be the solution in jquery javascript.

Comment: it can't be done without PHP or any other server-side language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **MUST** use some kind of server-side language (like PHP, ASP or many others) to upload files. There's no walkaround for that.

Think about it this way - javascript code runs on the client's machine.. it doesn't really care which server is hosting the website. So if this was doable using javascript only you should have been able to upload a file to any server.. not just the one you own. This is a security issue. Your server must be "ready" to receive the file and handle it properly such as validating the format of the file, limiting size, placing it in the right directory and changing it's name etc..

Even if you would like to do it without refreshing the page you will have to create some server-side file such as `upload.php` and use an AJAX request to upload the file to the server..

[Valum's File Uploader](https://github.com/Valums-File-Uploader/file-uploader) is an opensource project that deals with ajax file uploading. You can use it as a plugin.

Comment: I actually don't need to write the php code and doesn't want to combine the code just simple jquery or javascript code to handle it like in php there is  upload_dir and enctype helps to upload a file in jquery there will be too because its all about coding as well.

Comment: How the code would be in ajax? and don't refresh the page?

Comment: I've added a link to Valum's File Uploader, you will basically just have to place the PHP file on your server and use the relevant javascript functions

Comment: Actually I know to upload the file or anything with the help of php but would like to know about the jquery javascript that can help to upload the files at server as well.

Comment: You can "send" a file to the server using javascript however you must "recieve" the file using PHP code. The trick is usually done using `POST` or by targeting the form into a hidden `iframe` on the page (inside the iframe there's a PHP file that handles the upload)

Comment: iframe is another issue the file will never help with iframe it would be so different and useless. In jquery if we do send header a kind and then try to upload a file or image so?

Comment: iframe is not a bad solution for older browsers.. you just submit the form to the regular `upload.php` you've been using. the only difference is you submit to an iframe and not refresh the page. when the page inside the iframe is loaded you know the file exists on the server and you can use javascript to use it in your original page. get it? It seems like pure javascript to the user.

Comment: Yes i do and already know about it. Tell me that, Suppose can php code and javascript code be embed with eachother? like if i want to run php code through javascript? is it possible?

Comment: no. PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor as the name suggests is preprocessing the information on the server and delivers the ready code to the client (user's web-browser). Javascript on the other hand runs only when it gets to the user.. on the server Javascript is like HTML - only boring text - it gets the meaning on the client's machine. Javascript code can be created using PHP: <?php echo '<script>alert("hey")</script>'; ?> however the opposite is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You have to upload the file *to* somewhere. The somewhere needs to be prepared to accept the upload. Given a server that already supports [PUT](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6), you could (in theory) use client-side JavaScript to generate an HTTP PUT request (getting the file data with the new [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications)) and whatever authentication identification was needed, but this would usually be handled with server side programming.

You could use JavaScript for the server side programming (given a suitable server side programming environment). For instance: [Node.js with Express](http://howtonode.org/really-simple-file-uploads)

Comment: Yes it is cpanel server my project have to be in jquery or javascript its a task not to use php. and how the code should be in jquery will you please explain it. You know about jquery javascript more then me and i know you can solve this issue! How the name of file would be taken and how to upload it into given directory with file name size or just simple with extenssions. It will validate within the code of jquery as well.

Comment: jQuery has no functionality that particularly aids with the File API, so it isn't really relevant (the documentation for the File API linked above is pretty clear for the client side portion of this). As mentioned, the server has to be set up to accept whatever data is sent so the rest of it depends on the server set up. You can't save files on the server with client side code alone. If you could, then anybody could store any files they liked on anyone's web server.

Comment: So it means there is no solution with jquery javascript to upload file or image on even local machine or own server. like php can able to upload at server?

Comment: As mentioned, you need to have server side code and server side code can be written in JavaScript (so long as you have a server that supports JavaScript as a server side language). JavaScript can't write to arbitrary files on a file system, even on a local machine, since browsers impose a lot of limits for reasons of security.

Comment: Can you please explain how would it be if i use ajax as well in jquery or javascript?

Comment: As mentioned previously, the documentation for the File API linked above is pretty clear for the client side portion of this.

Comment: Suppose can php code and javascript code be embed with eachother? like if i want to run php code through javascript? is it possible?

Comment: PHP run on server, JavaScript run in browser. You can't embed or mix them. You can only use ajax in javascript to send some info to PHP and get some results from PHP.

Comment: @KomalShah — You can write the server side portion in PHP (or JavaScript or Perl or Python or COBOL or whatever else you like). The client makes HTTP requests. The server receives them and sends HTTP responses. The programming language used at either end is immaterial beyond needing to be supported by the platform.